# Issue when removing rows from JTable

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jtable, row

I made a `JTable` in my GUI application and i want to add rows and remove rows to it using add and remove buttons that i have already created, the problem is when removing a row I want to get the selected row index but I got a `NullPointerException` just when calling the `getSelectedRow()` method. I tried to google it and didn't found my question answer also I tried to read java documentation but I found that this method don't throw that exception in usual.

**the code:**

```
// creating the table
JTable table = new JTable(model);
    model.addColumn("NO.");
    model.addColumn("Name");
    model.addColumn("Status");
    table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
    table.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
    table.setShowGrid(false);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(28);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(222);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(100);
    table.setBackground(color);
    table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(350,250));
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
    center.add(scroll);

// adding records to it
public class AddEvent implements ActionListener{
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event){

    String text = write.getText();

    if (!text.equals("") && !text.contains(" ")){
        String view = "http://www." + text;
        write.setText(null);
        model.addRow(new Object[]{model.getRowCount()+1, view,"Active"});
    }

}
}


// to remove the selected row
public class RemoveEvent implements ActionListener{
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event){
          int index = table.getSelectedRow(); // it throws the exception here
      table.clearSelection();             
      System.out.println(index);
      if(index != -1){
      table.remove(index);
      }

    }

}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) It is better to change the `TableModel`.  Leave the table itself alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the exception is being thrown here

```
int index = table.getSelectedRow();
```

then `table` is *probably* `null`. For the `ActionListener` to work the class member variable `table` should be assigned to the `JTable` instance. Check that you are not shadowing the variable when it is being instantiated. Replace

```
JTable table = new JTable(model);
```

with

```
table = new JTable(model);
```

Comment: thanks, it's no longer throws the exception now, but it don't recognize the selected row and give me the value of index as -1

Comment: `-1` is returned when nothing is selected. Do you have a row selected?

Comment: yes, i select a row then pressing remove and nothing happened just it clears my selection (as i ordered) and send me -1

Answer (score 2):

Your posted code is not complete so all I can do is make a guess.

```
JTable table = new JTable(model);
```

This variable looks like a local variable, therefore it is not available to your other classes. Somewhere you probably defined a class variable:

```
JTable table; // this is null
```

Try this:

```
//JTable table = new JTable(model);
table = new JTable(model);
```

Also the data should be removed from the DefaultTableModel:

```
model.removeRow(...);
```

Comment: thanks, it's no longer throws the exception now, but it don't recognize the selected row and give me the value of index as -1